# How do I add ".setRegion" in updateUIView in SwiftUI MapKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to work with MapKit in SwiftUI. Previously I was using Storyboard. I can't do "uiView.setRegion" after calling "updateUIView" function to use MapKit. How can I solve this?

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0, longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

I get this error message: Value of type 'some UIView' has no member 'setRegion'

Comment: Your UIViewType should be MKMapView, but as I see it should not be in updateUIView, do it in makeUIView.

Answer (score 0):

please update the `func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context)` to `func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context)`

and inorder for the `updateUIView` to receive `uiView: as MKMapView` you will have to return MKMapView in the `makeUIView` function so something like this
`func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView`

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 2.0,
                                    longitudeDelta: 2.0)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate,
                                        span: span)
        uiView.setRegion(region,animated: true)
    }
}
```